# Does non static field makes any sense in a class that has only one instance

Tags: java

I came across a piece code and I got confused in the class definition.

The class is:

```
public class TestData {

    private ThreadLocal<Data> threadLocalData = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    private static final TestData testData = new TestData();
    private static final Logger ogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("data");


    private TestData() {
    }

    public static TestData getTestData() {
        return testData;
    }

    public void addTestData(String key) {
        Data data = new Data(key);

        threadLocalData.set(data);
    }

    public ThreadLocal<Data> getThreadLocalData() {
        return threadLocalData;
    }
}
```

This is referenced in another class as:

```
TestData.getTestData().getThreadLocalData().set(new Data());
```

So, my doubt is, if all the threads are using this class's single instance, which is:

```
private static final TestData testData = new TestData();
```

then does it make any sense to have non static members in the class?

```
    private ThreadLocal<Data> threadLocalData = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

If yes, then will there be separate copies of these non static members for each thread using the  testData instance?

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. This is actually `Singleton` design pattern.

Comment: I don't think this class is thread safe. But what you're looking at is a Singleton

Comment: @Transcendent yes, but that doesn't really explain it, does it?

Comment: @Stultuske: This question asks `Does it make any sense` and my comment says yes! (in short). I don't think any more explanation would be necessary as a comment!

Comment: @Transcendent which answers the question "does it make sense to having a class of which there can be only one instance", that doesn't answer the question static vs instance members for singletons

Comment: @Stultuske: I am not trying to answer `static vs instance members`, if the question is asking for that then we should vote for close!

Comment: The fewer things that are static, the fewer changes will need to be made if this class ever has more than 1 instance.

Comment: @Transcendent that is what he is asking about, whether it is making sense to have instance variables in a singleton, shouldn't they be static. And I did vote to close, since IMO this is mostly opinion.

Comment: The implementation tries to build a singleton. So the instance members are correct. 
However: Singleton in Java  should be implemented by using an enum.

Comment: @Transcendent, Thanks for the answer, but it will be better if you can explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it make any sense to have non static members

Sure, because there's still *some instance* of the class that exists

> there be separate copies of these non static members

No. There's only one static `TestData` instance, so only that instance's fields are stored

Comment: that means non static members, will also have just one instance through out the application lifetime, which is the part of the Singleton instance?

Comment: so, there is no sense in making them as non static? They shld be static to avoid the confusion.

Comment: The general answer is that if the variables belong to the instance, they should remain non static. The main purpose is to enforce encapsulation. Since you have public non static getter/setter methods, then encapsulation is broken

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, for the response, but can you explain, how it should be, so that it follows all of OOPs protocols.

Comment: It's your code; not really my place to suggest how you should structure it. There's plenty of resources elsewhere that say Singletons are an anti-pattern and you can use dependency injection as one alternative.